# Error creating a service in Linux to run when it starts

Tags: linux, debian

I want to use a bash script when starting, I used the option to create a service in systemd, but I get this error

I already tried changing the user from Kevin to root but that's not the point. I would like it to run through the user I already gave permissions, look at the route a hundred times. I need your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQJER.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3vim.png)

I tried changing the permissions to root but it is not what I expected because what I need is for it to be executed from the user since I am creating a script to open the browser (firefox) but in the root user the browser is restarted while opening From the normal one, the changes I made are not saved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: The script is getting errors, but you didn't post the script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.